# Sampling with and without replacement - Intuition

Tags: probability, sampling

Consider the problem of sampling without replacement. Suppose that we have an urn with $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls, and we choose a sample of $2$ balls without replacement. Let $X_i$ be the random variable that equals to $1$ if the $i$-th ball is red and $0$ otherwise. 
Obviously $P(X_1=1)=\frac{r}{r+b}$. Also, we have $$P(X_2=1)=P(X_2=1|X_1=1)P(X_1=1)+P(X_2=1|X_1=0)P(X_1=0)=\dots=\frac{r}{r+b}$$.

This seems a bit counter-intuitive to me since this is the result I would expect in the case of sampling with replacement. Can you give me some intuition of why this result is reasonable/intuitive?

Comment: Consider the scenario of a shuffled deck of playing cards.  If the deck is sufficiently shuffled, then regardless of whether you "cut the deck" or not the top card is going to be just as likely to be the ace of spades.  If you cut the deck exactly $n$ cards down and flip that card, then return the cut cards back to the top of the deck and continue dealing, this is essentially the same as not having cut the deck at all, dealing from the top like usual.  In the same way, you can on your first pull announce that the ball you pulled will be treated as the second ball pulled and pull first after.

Comment: The reason why you might choose to cut the cards in real life is to deter attempts at cheating where people might be inclined to not shuffle properly, perhaps by using sleight of hand tricks to keep track of various cards positions.  In standard probability problems however, we assume that the cards are fairly shuffled, making it so any permutation of the cards are equally likely to occur.